# android on ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, android, playonlinux, android-emulator

I have currently ubuntu 20.04 on my pc,
and as an old user of windows, I wanted to play my android games on pc, but blue stacks or nox doesn't support Linux.
so is there any alternatives to those 2 softwares on Linux other than anbox?
and how to install them, please.

Comment: Anbox is the only real 'alternative' unless you want to use a full Android Studio emulator environment, but that won't let you play them directly on the computer you'll be playing them on an 'emulated' android device.  Unfortunately, Android Emulation on Linux isn't as caught up as BlueStacks or such on Windows.

Comment: I run Android on an Ubuntu VirtualBox host. You can find pre-built Android Virtual machines if you Google. Makes installation very easy. I have been using Android 9.0-R2 (64bit).vdi but it is probably old now.

Comment: @Thomas Wardm thank you, but i already have anbox installed on my pc, and  the apk i try to install is giving me a `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113] ` .  and even when I used a beta apk it just opens and stay on black screen

Comment: @ c.s. Cameron can send a link on how to do it, please

Comment: @AdnaneRbt Anbox has been suffering Bitrot, and that may be part of the problem.  The second problem is that there's no *good* way to really run Android things on an Ubuntu infrastructure, which is what I was trying to state in my comment.

Comment: @Thomas Ward: Have you tried Android running on VirtualBox? Most the  apps I tried work OK, of coarse the ones requiring GPS and acceleration sensor don't do well.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron No, because the android-x86 systems are fairly 'old' compared to current Android OS apps that're developed for the newer systems and APIs.  That, and I have four android phones thank you very much so I have no need to *run* Android on my computer.  My point was that Anbox has been suffering bitrot and VBox+Android only runs the apps with compat layers equal to the older Android 9.0 API.

Comment: Personally I prefer making replies and answering questions based on personnel experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Android on Ubuntu VirtualBox

- Install VirtualBox from Ubuntu Software, (works better for me than from Virtualbox.org).
- Download https://sourceforge.net/projects/osboxes/files/v/vb/1-A-d/9.0/R2/andr-9.0-r2-VB-64bit.7z/download from https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/ Ignore any advertisements.
- Extract Android 9.0-R2 (64bit).vdi from the 7zip archive andr-9.0-r2-VB-64bit.7z. P7zip can be installed from Ubuntu Software if needed.
- Select `Use an existing virtual hard disk file` when setting up the VM.